# Ruby on Rails 4 count distinct with inner join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have created a validation rule to limit the number of records a member can create.

```
class Engine < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :engine_code, presence: true
  belongs_to :group
  delegate :member, to: :group

  validate :engines_within_limit, on: :create

  def engines_within_limit
    if self.member.engines(:reload).distinct.count(:engine_code) >= self.member.engine_limit
      errors.add(:engine, "Exceeded engine limit")
    end
  end
end
```

The above doesn't work, specifically this part,

```
self.member.engines(:reload).distinct.count(:engine_code)
```

The query it produces is

```
SELECT "engines".* 
FROM "engines" 
INNER JOIN "groups" 
ON "engines"."group_id" = "groups"."id" 
WHERE "groups"."member_id" = $1  [["member_id", 22]]
```

and returns the count `0` which is wrong

Whereas the following

```
Engine.distinct.count(:engine_code)
```

produces the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "engines"."engine_code") 
FROM "engines"
```

and returns `3` which is correct

What am I doing wrong? It is the same query just with a join?

Comment: What is the DB client name ? And what you want to count ? Not working means what? Error?

Comment: `self.member.engines(:reload).distinct.count(:engine_code)` counts 0. `Engine.distinct.count(:engine_code)` counts 3 which is correct and `self.member.engines(:reload).count` counts 8.

Comment: Which DB engine you are using ?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: `self.member.engines(:reload).distinct.count(:engine_code)` - for this SQL is  `join` you are getting... How >?

Comment: Because `engine` `belongs_to` `group` which `belongs_to` `member`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing [long chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79119/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-max-rose-collins), we found the below query to work :

```
self.member
    .engines(:reload)
    .count("DISTINCT engine_code")
```

Answer (score 1):

`AR::` means `ActiveRecord::` below.

The reason for the "wrong" result in the question is that the collection association isn't used correct. A collection association (e.g. `has_many`) for a record is not a `AR::Relation` it's a `AR::Associations::CollectionProxy`. It's a sub class of `AR::Relation`, and e.g. `distinct` is overridden.

`self.member.engines(:reload).distinct.count(:engine_code)` will cause this to happen:

- `self.member.engines(:reload)` is a
  `AR::Associations::CollectionProxy`
- `.distinct` on that will first
  fire the db read, then do a `.to_a` on the result and then doing
  "it's own" `distinct` which is doing a `uniq` on the array of records
  regarding the id of the records.
  The result is an array.
- `.count(:engine_code)` this is doing `Array#count` on the array which is returning
  `0` since no record in the array equals to the symbol `:engine_code`.

To get the correct result you should use the `relation` of the association proxy, **`.scope`**:
`self.member.engines(:reload).scope.distinct.count(:engine_code)`

I think it's a little bit confusing in Rails how collection associations is handled. Many of the "normal" methods for relations works as usual, e.g. this will work without using `.scope`:
`self.member.engines(:reload).where('true').distinct.count(:engine_code)`
that is because `where` isn't overridden by `AR::Associations::CollectionProxy`.
Perhaps it would be better to always have to use `.scope` when using the collection as a relation.